# How to sum the percent to be exactly 100.00%?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem how to sum the percent to be 100.00. i try use the "Round" but the result just show 99.93. Anyone got the idea?.

```
SELECT Sum(percent) 
FROM   (SELECT state, 
               jantina, 
               bilmale, 
               jds, 
               jumall, 
               Round(( bilmale * 100 / ( jumall ) ), 2) PERCENT, 
               ( jds ) * 100 / ( jumall )               AS p_jdk 
        FROM   (SELECT Timestamp(X.createdate) 
                             dattime 
                       , 
                       Upper(Date_format(X.createdate, '%d %M %Y'))      AS 
                       datenegeri, 
                       X.state, 
                       Upper(CASE 
                               WHEN g.ns_fender_desc = 'male' THEN 'LELAKI' 
                               WHEN g.ns_fender_desc = 'female' THEN 'PEREMPUAN' 
                               ELSE g.ns_fender_desc 
                             END)                                        jantina 
                       , 
                       Sum(CASE 
                             WHEN X.male = 1 THEN 1 
                             WHEN X.male = 0 THEN 1 
                             ELSE 0 
                           END)                                          bilmale 
                       , 
                       (SELECT Sum(CASE 
                                     WHEN Y.male = 1 THEN 1 
                                     WHEN Y.male = 0 THEN 1 
                                     ELSE 0 
                                   END) bilmale 
                        FROM   xyuser_userext Y 
                               JOIN tnsstate TS 
                                 ON TS.ns_state_id = Y.state 
                               LEFT JOIN tnsgender g 
                                      ON g.ns_gender_id = Y.male 
                        WHERE  Y.statususerext IN ( '0', '1', '2', '5' ) 
                               AND Y.state = X.state 
                               AND Date_format(X.createdate, '%d %M %Y') = 
                                   Date_format(Y.createdate, '%d %M %Y') 
                        GROUP  BY TS.ns_state_desc, 
                                  Date_format(X.createdate, '%d %M %Y')) jds, 
                       (SELECT Sum(CASE 
                                     WHEN Y.male = 1 THEN 1 
                                     WHEN Y.male = 0 THEN 1 
                                     ELSE 0 
                                   END) bilmale 
                        FROM   xyuser_userext Y 
                               JOIN tnsstate TS 
                                 ON TS.ns_state_id = Y.state 
                               LEFT JOIN tnsgender g 
                                      ON g.ns_gender_id = Y.male 
                        WHERE  Y.statususerext IN ( '0', '1', '2', '5' ))jumall 
                FROM   xyuser_userext X 
                       JOIN tnsstate TS 
                         ON TS.ns_state_id = X.state 
                       LEFT JOIN tnsgender g 
                              ON g.ns_gender_id = X.male 
                WHERE  X.statususerext IN ( '0', '1', '2', '5' ) 
                GROUP  BY TS.ns_state_desc, 
                          Date_format(X.createdate, '%d %M %Y'), 
                          X.male 
                ORDER  BY 1 ASC) AS A) AS b
```

Comment: Late holiday gift: [SQL formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)

Comment: You might also want to use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to show sample data.

Comment: not this that i want. what i want is how to get the 100.00% when i sum all the percent?.

Answer (score 0):

If you round only the result and not the individual items, it will be more accurate. Try using `SELECT Round(Sum(percent), 2)` and remove the Round from the percent calculation in the WHERE clause.

Comment: How about if i want to sum individual item to get the sum?

Comment: No problem -- just use Round only on the sum.